# Error loading shared class library

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, compilation, compiler-errors

I have an ASP.NET site/WPF/Windows phone app which all use three linked projects. In the data project (Myproject.DAL), I'm using references to `System.Data.SQLite` and `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`. The latter seems to be compiled for runtime version 2.0 in VS, even though I downloaded the 4.0 version (perhaps my misinterpretation).

[image]

When I try to load the ASP.NET 4 site, I get an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ChickenPing.DAL' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I remember having this problem in the past and it being caused by the System.Data.SQLite library, which is an x86 binary. I've updated and this is definitely not the cause. All projects are set to run as .NET 4 x86. Is there any way I can track down the actual cause of this? I'm guessing the must be a problem DLL somewhere, but MSBuild does not seem to report any problems.

Despite turning on Fusion logging, the only cryptic error I get is:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\CP
LOG: DisplayName = ChickenPing.DAL
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: ChickenPing.DAL | Domain ID: 9
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/echilon/Documents/CP/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\echilon\Documents\CP\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\echilon\Documents\CP\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/7bfa5a6e/c6574e91/ChickenPing.DAL.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/7bfa5a6e/c6574e91/ChickenPing.DAL/ChickenPing.DAL.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/echilon/Documents/CP/bin/ChickenPing.DAL.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Which doesn't really provide much insight.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a setting - "Enable 32 bit applications" in the "Advanced Settings" section of the app pool settings.[image: fix]